# SQL Stairstep Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need some help producing a MS SQL 2012 query that will match the desired stair-step output.  The rows summarize data by one date range (account submission date month), and the columns summarize it by another date range (payment date month)

Table 1: **Accounts** tracks accounts placed for collections.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [AccountID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SubmissionDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AccountID ASC))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1000', '2012-01-01', 1999.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1001', '2012-01-02', 100.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1002', '2012-02-05', 350.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1003', '2012-03-01', 625.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1004', '2012-03-10', 50.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] VALUES ('1005', '2012-03-10', 10.00)
```

Table 2: **Trans** tracks payments made

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Trans](
    [TranID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TranDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [TranAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Trans] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TranID ASC))

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1000, '2012-01-15', 300.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1000, '2012-02-15', 300.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1000, '2012-03-15', 300.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1002, '2012-02-20', 325.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1002, '2012-04-20', 25.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1003, '2012-03-24', 625.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1004, '2012-03-28', 31.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1004, '2012-04-12', 5.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1005, '2012-04-08', 7.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Trans] VALUES (1005, '2012-04-28', 3.00)
```

Here's what the desired output should look like

```
                                 *Total Payments in Each Month*
SubmissionYearMonth TotalAmount | 2012-01  2012-02  2012-03  2012-04 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-01             2099.00     |  300.00   300.00   300.00     0.00
2012-02             350.00      |           325.00     0.00    25.00
2012-03             685.00      |                    656.00    15.00
```

The first two columns sum Account.Amount grouping by month.

The last 4 columns sum the Tran.TranAmount, by month, for Accounts placed in the given month of the current row.

The query I've been working with feel close.  I just don't have the lag correct.
Here's the query I'm working with thus far:

```
Select SubmissionYearMonth, 
       TotalAmount,
       pt.[0] AS MonthOld0,
       pt.[1] AS MonthOld1,
       pt.[2] AS MonthOld2,
       pt.[3] AS MonthOld3,
       pt.[4] AS MonthOld4,
       pt.[5] AS MonthOld5,
       pt.[6] AS MonthOld6,
       pt.[7] AS MonthOld7,
       pt.[8] AS MonthOld8,
       pt.[9] AS MonthOld9,
       pt.[10] AS MonthOld10,
       pt.[11] AS MonthOld11,
       pt.[12] AS MonthOld12,
       pt.[13] AS MonthOld13

From (
       SELECT Convert(Char(4),Year(SubmissionDate)) + '-' + Right('00' + Convert(VarChar(2), DatePart(Month, SubmissionDate)),2) AS SubmissionYearMonth, 
       SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
       FROM   Accounts
       GROUP BY Convert(Char(4),Year(SubmissionDate)) + '-' + Right('00' + Convert(VarChar(2), DatePart(Month, SubmissionDate)),2)
     ) 
AS AccountSummary
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, SubmissionDate, TranDate) < 13
                   THEN DATEDIFF(Month, SubmissionDate, TranDate)
                   ELSE 13
              END AS PaymentMonthAge,
              TranAmount
       FROM Trans INNER JOIN Accounts ON Trans.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID
       Where Convert(Char(4),Year(TranDate)) + '-' + Right('00' + Convert(VarChar(2), DatePart(Month, TranDate)),2)
             = AccountSummary.SubmissionYearMonth
       ) as TransTemp
       PIVOT (SUM(TranAmount)
              FOR PaymentMonthAge IN ([0],
                                      [1],
                                      [2],
                                      [3],
                                      [4],
                                      [5],
                                      [6],
                                      [7],
                                      [8],
                                      [9],
                                      [10],
                                      [11],
                                      [12],
                                      [13])) as TransPivot
) as pt
```

It's producing the following output:

```
SubmissionYearMonth TotalAmount MonthOld0 MonthOld1 MonthOld2 MonthOld3 ...
2012-01             2099.00     300.00    NULL      NULL      NULL      ...
2012-02             350.00      325.00    300.00    NULL      NULL      ...
2012-03             685.00      656.00    NULL      300.00    NULL      ...
```

As for the column date headers.  I'm not sure what the best option is here.  I could add an additional set of columns and create a calculated value that I could use in the resulting report.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/272e5/1/0

Comment: **Excellent** job including sample data and queries.  This is how every question should be written!

Comment: @mellamokb: Plus a link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and it would be perfect :)

Comment: @juergend: Indeed.  Here's the OP's query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56223/1

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56223/1 does that auto default to 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198643/thomas), I used your response as inspiration for the following solution I ended up using.

I first create a SubmissionDate, TranDate cross join skeleton date matrix, that I later use to join on the AccountSummary and TranSummary data.

The resulting query output isn't formatted in columns, per TranDate month.  Rather I'm using output in a SQL Server Reporting Services matrix, and using a column grouping, based off the TranSummaryMonthNum column, to get the desired formatted output.

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/272e5/59/0)

```
;
WITH 
    --Generate a list of Dates, from the first SubmissionDate, through today.
    --Note: Requires the use of: 'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)' to generate a list with more than 100 dates.
    CTE_AutoDates AS
    ( Select Min(SubmissionDate) as FiscalDate
      From Accounts
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(Day, 1, FiscalDate)
      FROM CTE_AutoDates
      WHERE DATEADD(Day, 1, FiscalDate) <= GetDate()
    ),

    FiscalDates As
    ( SELECT FiscalDate,
             DATEFROMPARTS(Year(FiscalDate), Month(FiscalDate), 1) as FiscalMonthStartDate  
      FROM CTE_AutoDates
      --Optionaly filter Fiscal Dates by the last known Math.Max(SubmissionDate, TranDate)
      Where FiscalDate <= (Select Max(MaxDate)
                           From (Select Max(SubmissionDate) as MaxDate From Accounts
                                 Union All 
                                 Select Max(TranDate) as MaxDate From Trans
                                ) as MaxDates
                         )
    ),

    FiscalMonths as
    ( SELECT Distinct FiscalMonthStartDate 
      FROM FiscalDates
    ),

    --Matrix to store the reporting date groupings for the Account submission and payment periods.
    SubmissionAndTranMonths AS
    ( Select AM.FiscalMonthStartDate as SubmissionMonthStartDate,
             TM.FiscalMonthStartDate as TransMonthStartDate,
             DateDiff(Month, (Select Min(FiscalMonthStartDate) From FiscalMonths), TM.FiscalMonthStartDate) as TranSummaryMonthNum
      From   FiscalMonths AS AM
             Join FiscalMonths AS TM
             ON TM.FiscalMonthStartDate >= AM.FiscalMonthStartDate
    ),

    AccountData as
    ( Select A.AccountID, 
             A.Amount,
             FD.FiscalMonthStartDate as SubmissionMonthStartDate
      From   Accounts as A
           Inner Join FiscalDates as FD
             ON A.SubmissionDate = FD.FiscalDate
    ),


    TranData as
    ( Select T.AccountID,
             T.TranAmount,
             AD.SubmissionMonthStartDate,
             FD.FiscalMonthStartDate as TranMonthStartDate
      From   Trans as T
           Inner Join AccountData as AD
             ON T.AccountID = AD.AccountID
           Inner Join FiscalDates AS FD
             ON T.TranDate = FD.FiscalDate
    ),

    AccountSummaryByMonth As
    ( Select ASM.FiscalMonthStartDate,
             Sum(AD.Amount) as TotalSubmissionAmount
      From   FiscalMonths as ASM
           Inner Join AccountData as AD
             ON ASM.FiscalMonthStartDate = AD.SubmissionMonthStartDate
      Group By
             ASM.FiscalMonthStartDate
    ),

    TranSummaryByMonth As
    ( Select STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate,
             STM.TransMonthStartDate,
             STM.TranSummaryMonthNum,
             Sum(TD.TranAmount) as TotalTranAmount
      From   SubmissionAndTranMonths as STM
           Inner Join TranData as TD
             ON STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate = TD.SubmissionMonthStartDate
                AND STM.TransMonthStartDate = TD.TranMonthStartDate
      Group By
             STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate,
             STM.TransMonthStartDate,
             STM.TranSummaryMonthNum
    )

--#Inspect 1
--Select * From SubmissionAndTranMonths
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

--#Inspect 1 Results
--SubmissionMonthStartDate TransMonthStartDate TranSummaryMonthNum
--2012-01-01               2012-01-01          0
--2012-01-01               2012-02-01          1
--2012-01-01               2012-03-01          2
--2012-01-01               2012-04-01          3
--2012-02-01               2012-02-01          1
--2012-02-01               2012-03-01          2
--2012-02-01               2012-04-01          3
--2012-03-01               2012-03-01          2
--2012-03-01               2012-04-01          3
--2012-04-01               2012-04-01          3

--#Inspect 2
--Select * From AccountSummaryByMonth
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

--#Inspect 2 Results
--FiscalMonthStartDate TotalSubmissionAmount
--2012-01-01           2099.00
--2012-02-01           350.00
--2012-03-01           685.00

--#Inspect 3
--Select * From TranSummaryByMonth
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

--#Inspect 3 Results
--SubmissionMonthStartDate TransMonthStartDate TranSummaryMonthNum TotalTranAmount
--2012-01-01               2012-01-01          0                   300.00
--2012-01-01               2012-02-01          1                   300.00
--2012-01-01               2012-03-01          2                   300.00
--2012-02-01               2012-02-01          1                   325.00
--2012-02-01               2012-04-01          3                   25.00
--2012-03-01               2012-03-01          2                   656.00
--2012-03-01               2012-04-01          3                   15.00

Select STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate,
       ASM.TotalSubmissionAmount,
       STM.TransMonthStartDate,
       STM.TranSummaryMonthNum,
       TSM.TotalTranAmount
From   SubmissionAndTranMonths as STM
     Inner Join AccountSummaryByMonth as ASM
       ON STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate = ASM.FiscalMonthStartDate
     Left Join TranSummaryByMonth AS TSM
       ON STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate = TSM.SubmissionMonthStartDate
          AND STM.TransMonthStartDate = TSM.TransMonthStartDate
Order By STM.SubmissionMonthStartDate, STM.TranSummaryMonthNum
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

--#Results
--SubmissionMonthStartDate TotalSubmissionAmount TransMonthStartDate TranSummaryMonthNum TotalTranAmount
--2012-01-01               2099.00               2012-01-01           0                  300.00
--2012-01-01               2099.00               2012-02-01           1                  300.00
--2012-01-01               2099.00               2012-03-01           2                  300.00
--2012-01-01               2099.00               2012-04-01           3                  NULL
--2012-02-01               350.00                2012-02-01           1                  325.00
--2012-02-01               350.00                2012-03-01           2                  NULL
--2012-02-01               350.00                2012-04-01           3                  25.00
--2012-03-01               685.00                2012-03-01           2                  656.00
--2012-03-01               685.00                2012-04-01           3                  15.00
```

Comment: Dear Nathan, if someone helped you substantially with your query, then in my opinion you should select that person's answer instead of providing your own and selecting it.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, we can use the Format function to make the date pretty. There is no need to group by the strings. Instead, I find it useful to use the proper data type for as long as I can and only use Format or Convert on display (or not at all and let the middle tier handle the display).

In this solution, I arbitrarily assumed the earliest TransDate and extract from it, the first day of that month. However, one could easily replace that expression with a static value of the start date desired and this solution would take that and the next 12 months.

```
With SubmissionMonths As
  (
  Select DateAdd(d, -Day(A.SubmissionDate) + 1, A.SubmissionDate) As SubmissionMonth
    , A.Amount
  From dbo.Accounts As A
  )
  , TranMonths As
  (
  Select DateAdd(d, -Day(Min( T.TranDate )) + 1, Min( T.TranDate )) As TranMonth
      , 1 As MonthNum
  From dbo.Accounts As A
    Join dbo.Trans As T
      On T.AccountId = A.AccountId
    Join SubmissionMonths As M
      On A.SubmissionDate >= M.SubmissionMonth
        And A.SubmissionDate < DateAdd(m,1,SubmissionMonth)
  Union All
  Select DateAdd(m, 1, TranMonth), MonthNum + 1
  From TranMonths
  Where MonthNum < 12
  )
  , TotalBySubmissionMonth As
  (
  Select M.SubmissionMonth, Sum( M.Amount ) As Total
  From SubmissionMonths As M
  Group By M.SubmissionMonth
  )
Select Format(SMT.SubmissionMonth,'yyyy-MM') As SubmissionMonth, SMT.Total
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 1 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month1
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 2 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month2
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 3 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month3
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 4 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month4
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 5 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month5
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 6 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month6
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 7 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month7
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 8 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month8
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 9 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month9
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 10 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month10
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 11 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month11
  , Sum( Case When TM.MonthNum = 12 Then T.TranAmount End ) As Month12
From TotalBySubmissionMonth As SMT
  Join dbo.Accounts As A
    On A.SubmissionDate >= SMT.SubmissionMonth
      And A.SubmissionDate < DateAdd(m,1,SMT.SubmissionMonth)
  Join dbo.Trans As T
    On T.AccountId = A.AccountId
  Join TranMonths As TM
    On T.TranDate >= TM.TranMonth
      And T.TranDate < DateAdd(m,1,TM.TranMonth)
Group By SMT.SubmissionMonth, SMT.Total
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/272e5/54)

Comment: This looks very promising.  I'm going to fiddle with it a bit and see if I can use this implementation.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Also, the OP should have marked your answer as selected because it was instrumental in him getting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following query pretty much returns what you want.  You need to do the to operations separately.  I just join the results together:

```
 select a.yyyymm, a.Amount,
        t201201, t201202, t201203, t201204
 from (select LEFT(convert(varchar(255), a.submissiondate, 121), 7) as yyyymm,
              SUM(a.Amount) as amount
       from Accounts a
       group by  LEFT(convert(varchar(255), a.submissiondate, 121), 7) 
      ) a left outer join
      (select LEFT(convert(varchar(255), a.submissiondate, 121), 7) as yyyymm,
              sum(case when trans_yyyymm = '2012-01' then tranamount end) as t201201,
              sum(case when trans_yyyymm = '2012-02' then tranamount end) as t201202,
              sum(case when trans_yyyymm = '2012-03' then tranamount end) as t201203,
              sum(case when trans_yyyymm = '2012-04' then tranamount end) as t201204
       from Accounts a join
            (select t.*, LEFT(convert(varchar(255), t.trandate, 121), 7) as trans_yyyymm
             from trans t
            ) t
            on a.accountid = t.accountid
       group by LEFT(convert(varchar(255), a.submissiondate, 121), 7)
      ) t
      on a.yyyymm = t.yyyymm
 order by 1
```

I am getting a NULL where you have a 0.00 in two cells.

Comment: The date range endpoints are not know at querytime.  Every time the query is run, it will produce a list of rows for all known Account Submission months, along with a fixed or potentially variable number of payment month summary columns.

A few extra nulls are not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The following query exactly duplicates the results of [your final query in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296593/57611) but takes no more than 1/30th the CPU (or better), plus is a whole lot simpler.

If I had the time & energy I am sure I could find even more improvements... my gut tells me I might not have to hit the `Accounts` table so many times. But in any case, it's a huge improvement and should perform very well even for very large result sets.

See [the SqlFiddle for it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/272e5/70).

```
WITH L0 AS (SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L0, L0 B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L1, L1 B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L2, L2 B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 N FROM L3, L2 B),
Nums AS (SELECT N = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L4),
Anchor AS (
   SELECT MinDate = DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '20000101', Min(SubmissionDate)), '20000101')
   FROM dbo.Accounts
),
MNums AS (
   SELECT N
   FROM Nums
   WHERE
      N <= DateDiff(month,
         (SELECT MinDate FROM Anchor),
         (SELECT Max(TranDate) FROM dbo.Trans)
      ) + 1
),
A AS (
   SELECT
      AM.AccountMo,
      Amount = Sum(A.Amount)
   FROM
      dbo.Accounts A
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '20000101', A.SubmissionDate), '20000101')
      ) AM (AccountMo)
   GROUP BY
      AM.AccountMo
), T AS (
   SELECT
      AM.AccountMo,
      TM.TranMo,
      TotalTranAmount = Sum(T.TranAmount)
   FROM
      dbo.Accounts A
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '20000101', A.SubmissionDate), '20000101')
      ) AM (AccountMo)
      INNER JOIN dbo.Trans  T
         ON A.AccountID = T.AccountID
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '20000101', T.TranDate), '20000101')
      ) TM (TranMo)
   GROUP BY
      AM.AccountMo,
      TM.TranMo
)
SELECT
   SubmissionStartMonth = A.AccountMo,
   TotalSubmissionAmount = A.Amount,
   M.TransMonth,
   TransMonthNum = N.N - 1,
   T.TotalTranAmount
FROM
   A
   INNER JOIN MNums N
      ON N.N >= DateDiff(month, (SELECT MinDate FROM Anchor), A.AccountMo) + 1
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TransMonth = DateAdd(month, N.N - 1, (SELECT MinDate FROM Anchor))
   ) M
   LEFT JOIN T
      ON A.AccountMo = T.AccountMo
      AND M.TransMonth = T.TranMo
ORDER BY
   A.AccountMo,
   M.TransMonth;
```